# Is it possible to convert a .py to single .exe file holding all the images and icon files

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

Currently, I compressed it to a `.exe` file which has a dependency on the image and icon file. Is it possible to convert/compress `.py` to `.exe` with all the images included in the `.py` project?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: read all documentation for `pyinstaller`